Haskell PatternSynonyms bang strictness annotation
The User Guide comment says this is not allowed, but the explicitly bidir form is

pattern StrictJust a = Just !a



pattern StrictJust a <- Just !a where
  StrictJust !a = Just a


Given that the compiler splits an implicitly bidir form into two separate artefacts anyway, is there some deep reason I can't go
pattern StrictJust !a = Just !a
--                 ^^ parse error here

and get the compiler to turn it into the explicitly bidir form for me?

And more generally allow anything on LHS that would be valid in an 'underneath' line, but ignore it in the matcher?
pattern HeadC x | xs <- [] = x:xs     -- default to build a singleton


Questions about the reasoning behind compiler syntax/design choices and possible improvements would probably better be directed to the ghc-devs mailing list, or maybe filed as an issue on the GHC GitLab if you want to propose something or think it's a bug.  Or, if you're just looking for agreement from peers with no expectation that anything useful will be done about it, the /r/haskell reddit would be a good fit.

https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/discussions/670
